# P9 Server Ubuntu

Tags: server

I am on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS running on Windows Subsystem for Linux.

I would like an up to date easy guide of setting up a P9 server so I can access linux files from Windows.

Comment: [This one](https://support.panorama9.com/hc/en-us/articles/203568828-Installing-the-P9-agent-on-Linux#debian) appears to be the latest. What doesn't work?

Comment: why P9, why not samba?

Comment: actually you don't even need to set up a file sharing system at all : https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/127857-access-wsl-linux-files-windows-10-a.html files are directly accessible already :)

Comment: @tatsu it is not recommended to do it that way.

Comment: why? I don't see any issues personally :(